I've Problems with ANTLR4 to parse key-value-pairs
I want to parse this with ANTLR4:
; this is a comment
dummykey=dummy string  100 #!; this is a comment
firstname=peter mike
name=mc miller

This is the grammar:
grammar KEYVALUE;

COMMENT: ';' .*? ('\r'? '\n' | EOF) -> skip;

file: line* EOF;

line: Space* keyValuePair;

keyValuePair:
    key EQ value 
    {       
       String k = $key.text;
       String v = $value.text; 

       System.out.println("\nkey   : `" + k + "`");
       System.out.println("value : `" + v + "`");
     };

key: AlphaNum+;

value: valueChar+ EOL;

valueChar: Char;

EOL: LineBreak | EOF;
EQ: '=';

LineBreak: '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
Space: ' ' | '\t' | '\f';
AlphaNum: [a-zA-Z0-9];
Char: .; 

When i start it with:  more test.txt |grun parser.KEYVALUE file -gui
I get these error messages and there are no values.
key   : dummykey
value : ``
line 2:14 mismatched input ' ' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 2:21 mismatched input ' ' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 2:26 mismatched input ' ' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 2:27 extraneous input '#' expecting {Space, AlphaNum}
line 3:10 mismatched input 'p' expecting Char
key   : firstname
value : ``
line 3:15 mismatched input ' ' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 3:20 mismatched input '\r\n' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 4:5 mismatched input 'm' expecting Char
key   : name
value : ``
line 4:7 mismatched input ' ' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}
line 4:14 mismatched input '' expecting {'=', AlphaNum}

You're trying to guide lexing through the parser. Antlr does not work this way. Think of the lexer tokenizing before parsing ever starts. So, print out the tokens and see what you get. It is not what you expect. The lexer works by two rules: 1) the rule that matches the longest string is selected. 2) if two or more rules can match the same string, the first one wins.

Also, remove EOF from this rule: COMMENT: ';' .*? ('\r'? '\n' | EOF) -> skip;. You should not use EOF on the right hand side of a lexer rule. It makes no sense, and should be flagged by the tool. Change skip to channel(HIDDEN). COMMENT: ';' .*? ('\r'? '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN);. Using HIDDEN will allow you to examine the off-channel tokens.
